# LibreOffice help files not installed

Tags: 22.04

I have installed LibreOffice,using snap, but the help files have not installed how can I download and install the help files?

Comment: (please note: this detail maybe incorrect as I've not tested your issue but have experienced issues with snap/help on *jammy* (22.04) & *kinetic* in QA that are known bugs, and are *fix committed* & *fix released* when systems were fully upgraded; I've not re-tested for them, but have you checked it's still an issue after you've ensured the system is fully upgraded... Do note: the issue I'm thinking of relates to `snapd` & may **not** be your actual issue - just a thought and could be just completely off as you want local help; issue with bugs were accessing help if not available locally)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you are interested in installing the help files with snap too. If you don´t mind about how, you could get the help files from the downloads page (e.g. https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download/?type=deb-x86_64 ), decompress the tar.gz and run

```
sudo apt install xxx.deb
```

to install the package with the help files.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered, still no help.